# Are these considered to be Javascript closures?

Tags: javascript, closures

Wanting to get something straight here...so I have 2 questions

**The function below creates a closure.**

```
function Foo(message){
    var msg = message;

    return function Bar(){ 
        this.talk = function(){alert(msg); }
    }
};
```

**Q: Which function is the closure, `Foo` or `Bar`?**
I always thought the closure to be `Foo`, because it closes-over `Bar` once `Bar` is returned.

Next...

Below is the definition of an anonymous function:

```
()();
```

**Q: Is the inner-function within this anonymous function also a closure?**

```
(function(){ /* <-- Is this function also a closure? */ })();
```

Comment: You don't need those `<br/>` tags in your question. Also, `()();` is absolutely not a definition of an anonymous function.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, I was always told ()(); is an anonymous function.  If not, what is it called?

Comment: `()();` does not have a special name. The first `()` is the grouping operator which forces the content to be treated as an expression. This is used to force the function definition to be an expression and not be treated as a statement. The second `()` calls the function in this case but it would be an error if the result of evaluating the grouping operator is not a function. An anonymous function is simply a function without a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use first principles here.  Javascript uses *lexical scoping*.  This means the scope of an execution context is determined by how the code is **defined** (lexical).

I would say the **definition** of the function `Bar` is what *causes* the closure to be created, because `msg` is "closed-in" in the function.

The actual creation of the closure happens at runtime (which is somewhat of a tautological statement, since nothing in a computer program happens until it is run), because in order to determine the value of `msg`, in `Bar`, when `Bar` is executed, the interpreter needs to know the value of the variable when `Foo` is executed, and so on up the chain.

I'll give two answers to your question.  The pedantic answer is: neither function by itself is the closure.  It's the *definition* of variables within functions, combined with the execution context of functions when they are run, that is defines the closure.  The common answer is: any function which closes over a variable is a closure (Bar in your case).

Consider the problem everyone encounters when using Javascript.

```
function A(x) {
   var y = x, fs = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       fs.push(function(){
         console.log (i + " " + x);
       })
   }

   fs.forEach(function(g){g()})  
}

A('hi')
```

Most people would say this would produce the output 'hi 1' followed by 'hi 2' followed by 'hi 3'.  However, it produces 'hi 3' 3 times.  If just the definition of the function being added to the array, while using variables defined in the outer function, created the closure, how can this be?

It's because you need the *execution context* to define the closure, which doesn't happen until runtime.  At the execution of the functions in the array, `i` has the value `3`.  In the `forEach` statement, that's the execution context, which is why the output always uses 3.

Comment: You mean "... when Foo is excuted." I think.

Comment: How do you mean? The existence of `Bar` and it's use of `msg` is what causes the closure.

Answer (score 1):

`Bar` is the closure.

We say that `Bar` *closes over* the variable `msg` in its environment.

Most often the word *closure* means: a function that uses at least one variable that’s defined in an enclosing scope, in an enclosing function.

To answer your second question: `(function(){ ... })()` is just what it looks like: one anonymous function, not two. Unless it’s nested inside another function, you generally wouldn’t call it a closure. However, functions nested inside that anonymous function can be closures (and often are).

Comment: +1 for the outright answer...I wish I could vote-for two answers.